# C# TCP Multithread Server and Client with requirements

Tags: tcp

I am currently working on TCP multithread server and clients written in C#. I was looking around on Google and tried more than 5 examples but seems none of them can serve all requirements. As I am not familiar with networking, so it would be appreciated if someone can point me to the right direction.

Here are the requirements I need:

1. multithread, I need a server which can handle multiple clients, though those clients do not need to communicate each other.
2. continous operations, after clients connected to the server, they need to keep sending messages to each other, until the server drops all the clients. The server needs to identify each client. The clients do not need to disconnect from server on themselves, normally.
3. disconnection notification, most of those examples found on Google do not have this feature, I need the server to know when the connected client disconnects, so the server can notifiy the user.

Actually the closest example I found is this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22918/How-To-Use-the-SocketAsyncEventArgs-Class

But the problem I am facing is that the messages are inside the class Token, I included all those classes in my Window Form Application, which is my main application. Those information like client ID, client status, or actions to clients, will be performed in the Form. I dont know how to bring those variables from Token class to my Form.

This is another example seems can suit my purpose:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2866/Multi-threaded-NET-TCP-Server-Examples

But I am not sure how to change it since it blocked my Form from displaying.

Thanks for help.

Comment: There really isn't a question in there.

Answer (score 1):

Some months later... First, you have to keep in mind that the window form isn't async native, you have to implement invoke methods to use the tcp AsyncCallback. Elsewhere to handle clients, you have to create a new dictionary like :

```
Dictionary<string, System.Net.Sockets> clientList;
```

It could be int in case of database ids or simply you could use the native system handle :

`this.anonymousSock.Client.Handle`

And adding them like this :

```
clientList.Add("ID", this.anonymousSock);
```

Finaly :

```
public void Send(string data, string id)
    {
        Socket Client = this.clientList[id];
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        Client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, 
            byteData.Length, 0, 
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), Client);
    }
```

While receiving, you could in this case identify client by checking your sockets entries or by using tokens.

And then no cpu/memory burn with threads.